# How can I put my iMessage settings on my phone number instead of my apple ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, apple-id

I've just updated my iPhone 4s to ios 7.0.3 and I've set up a new apple ID but iMessage doesn't work on my phone even after I activated iMessage in settings.

It used to work with my phone number before but I cannot set it on my phone number anymore. I can just choose my Apple ID to send and receive iMessages.

When I try to send iMessages it doesn't work and nobody can send me iMessages.

Comment: And updating to 7.0.4? You have iMessage turned on I hope and as for your Send & Receive addresses?

Comment: Is your phone number listed under `Settings > Messages > Send & Receive`?